# why when I change the device type in the inspect window the whole structure of my website changes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, structure

[this is the viewport the device type is mobile[and this is when the device is desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUeJz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRGJE.png)
when I change the device type in the inspect window from desktop to mobile the fixed elements on the right get out of the viewport and I have to zoom out to see them, just the whole structure start looking messed up, and when I hover on the empty space there is no element placed in that area it's just an empty spot.

I tried some of the parent's attributes, and checking the right and left values, but none of them worked, frankly I suspect that maybe there is problem in the structure of the website, I would be glad if you could clarify the reason for this error